# Hello is reading novel with a little bit of romace alright (between non mehram) or is it impermissible

Tags: sharia

Hello I want to know is it alright to read fiction novel that has some aspect of romance in it between non mehrams,the main theme of the novel is not romance,it contain thing like dating each other and interacting with each other and also description of the non Muslim cloth that is contrary to sharia and also maybe kiss one or two time only but nothing beyond that,well basically you could say it is Japanese school genre light novel. The thing is we are only reading it and not acting upon it or thinking of commiting a sin so will it be sin to read it. Also give me a definite answer plz since according to quran and hadith that I know it is acting upon that sin not reading them that is sinful so plz answer what the scholar say about it

Answer (score 2):

Assalamu Walaikum

Muslims are free to read whatever genres of books s/he likes; however, they must avoid anything that arouses unlawful sexual desire.

In Islam, prose and poetry are considered an expression of feelings and emotions that reflect tenderness and sensitivity. Islam does not suppress feelings and emotions. Prose and poetry can be, in many cases, an influential means toward psychological and social reform. It is worthy to mention that the means takes the same rulings as their objectives.

1- If romantic novels or poems call for social reform, express noble feelings and call for love among people and the like, it is then permissible to read such novels.

2- It is not permissible to read romantic novels if they incite the reader to immorality or contain anything that contradicts the Islamic creed.

Almighty Allah knows best.

Source: Dar al-Ifta al-Misriyyah

Comment: I understand that I should not read it if it incite me to do something immoral and I know that I can control myself,in that case would It be permissible to read